# cant import projects from dev.eclipse.org cvs

Tags: java, osgi, server, equinox

I am trying to follow a tutorial that creates an equinox runtime embedded in a jetty server.
however, when i try to import the project org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty among others.

the error says:

The following errors occurred while importing projects. Some projects may not be loaded.
Could not connect to :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse: I/O exception occurred: Connection refused: cvs [pserver aborted]: /cvsroot/eclipse: no such repository
Connection refused: cvs [pserver aborted]: /cvsroot/eclipse: no such repository

i also get the same error when trying to import the team project set found here: https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php
the tutorial i am following is here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/08/15/building-your-equinox-based-appserver-part-1/

any help on this matter is much appreciated

Many thanks

Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse shut down their CVS servers some time back. That blog post is old. You'll need to adjust to use Eclipse's new git servers.